# Change url from localhost/name/index.php to localhost/name/home

Tags: php

I'm trying to change the name from my url's to for example home instead of index.php. I've read you can do that with the `.htaccess` file but for that you need Apache stuff and I don't have anything like that.

Isn't there any more easy way to change the url?

Comment: How are you running PHP without Apache? Do you have a different webserver?

Answer (score -1):

Yes, there is an easy way to change the URL without using the .htaccess file. This can typically be done by using a web framework or a CMS (Content Management System) such as WordPress, Laravel, or Django. These frameworks and CMSs have built-in functionality for handling URL routing, which allows you to define custom URLs for your pages.

Another way is to use a URL rewriting module provided by your web server software such as IIS URL Rewrite for IIS web server, or mod_rewrite for Apache. These modules allow you to rewrite URLs on the server side without requiring changes to the actual file structure on the server.

Without more information about your web server, it's difficult to give more specific instructions. But you could check the documentation or the community forum of your web server or the language framework you're using to find more information about how to change the URLs in your application.

Comment: I've been trying with the .htaccess file but it keeps erroring when I put this to remove the .php: `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
</IfModule>`

Comment: @stavros of course this won't work, when you request `/name/home`, but only have an `index.php` inside that `name` folder. You would need to have a file named `home.php`.